# How can I trouble-shoot line-ending settings in Git?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Sometimes when I am working with Git (EGit with Eclipse to be exact), EGit thinks I have changed an entire file, when I have only changed a few lines. This can happen after I made a commit that went smoothly. My colleagues say I'm somehow changing the settings in Eclipse, probably for line settings. I am not consciously changing the line ending settings. Does anyone know how I could have unintentionally changed settings in Git/Egit, or have any other suggestions for troubleshooting my workflow?

Comment: are you and your mates working on different OS? This is normally the cause. The end-of-line is differently represented in windows and linux, so you upload a file with a codification and then they change it again and so

Comment: All working in windows, but sometimes it helps to set line endings in Eclipse to Unix. Is it possible that people using command line git in Windows (which has a unix-like interface) would change windows files to have unix line endings?

Comment: This problem is helped by using git bash. My co-workers were sticking to the git bash, and I was using EGit. I switched to using the git bash and things are running smoothly.